# Filtering results by multiple checkbox lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have two different sets of checkbox lists. I want them to filter results based on an "AND" not an "OR." I've tried lots of variations of the JavaScript, and can't make it so that it's any of Set A *AND* any of Set B. Help?

Here's the HTML and JS, with a jsfiddle after that to see it in action:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend>Status</legend>
    <input id="passed" type="checkbox" value="passed" checked class="status">
    <label for="passed">Passed</label>
    <br />
    <input id="failed" type="checkbox" value="failed" checked class="status">
    <label for="failed">Failed</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend>Issues</legend>
    <input id="Jobs" type="checkbox" value="jobs" checked class="subject">
    <label for="jobs">Jobs</label>
    <br />
    <input id="immigration" type="checkbox" value="immigration" checked class="subject">
    <label for="immigration">Immigration</label>
</fieldset>

<div class="document pass jobs">
    Item A
</div>

<div class="document failed immigration">
    Item B
</div>
```

For the JS, I've tried a couple different things, mostly by using the classes of the checkboxes (so, `[type=checkbox].status` kinds of stuff). But here's the most basic version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
        $('.document ').hide();
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
            var value = $(this).attr('value');
            $('.' + value).show();
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ogwofbak/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One interesting thing you can do, is to do it the other way around using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to convert OR to AND.

First, show everything, then go over all the inputs that are not checked, and hide the items corresponding to that checkbox that is not checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
        $('.document').show();
        $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function() {
            var value = $(this).attr('value');
            $('.' + value).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Also as it is mentioned to another answer here, you have a typo in your html. The input value is `passed` but the class in the div is `pass`.

Comment: Can you help me out with one more thing? If "Item A" has BOTH jobs AND immigration, then when you only check one of those boxes it should appear. With yours, it has to match ALL the issues. Any way around that? It should be ANY matches in Set A (and) ANY matches in Set B. We figured out the And part, but now the Anys within Set B don't work.

Comment: So you have two sets of boolean variables, S1 and S2. You want to find any item that matches OR(S1) AND OR(S2) is true, right?

Comment: In that case you should implement a more complex logic, it cant be done as simple as this. I would suggest loop over all the check boxes and put their true/false value into a map. This map should also include the Set number of the checkbox is belong to. Then loop over all items and show/hide them based on the map's values and set numbers. If you create a jsfiddle with more data, i can help you more.

Comment: I appreciate that. Here's the jsfiddle with more data. You'll see I added that items may have multiple issues associated with them. http://jsfiddle.net/elicash/ogwofbak/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.document ').hide();
    var checked = '';
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        checked += '.' + value;
    });
    $(checked).show();
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ogwofbak/5/

PS. You have typo problem: first input has `passed` value, but `div` has `pass` class.

Comment: Appreciate the help. But when everything's selected, it should show all results. When nothing's selected, it shouldn't show anything. (Check and uncheck a box in your version and you'll see what I mean.) http://jsfiddle.net/elicash/ogwofbak/9/

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is iterate over each group, gather all checked items of each group and then concatinate classes, something like:

```
$('.' + val1 + '.' + val2).show();
```

In this way you will get something like:

```
$('.pass.jobs').show();
```

which is exactly what you're looking for.